# MySQL: how do I add up values if the occur on the same day?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a column of datetimes, and a column of values.
How do I add up all teh values that occur on the same day?
so like... midnight:01 to 23:5 => add all the records that occur in that time period.

then group by day.

bit hard to explain. sadness.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that your next question [has already been answered on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range)...

Comment: @pilcrow: That question is for date *generation* - this for *summation* of values over a given date.

Comment: Right Ponies, and the very common follow-up is, how do I summarize those dates absent from my original data set.

Comment: nope, i'm doing something completely different =p

Comment: Ah, well, visions of the future are hazy. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT SUM(t.value_column)
  FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY DATE(t.datetime_column)
```

The [DATE function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) only captures the year/month/day portion - time is ignored, so anything on that date will be grouped together.

Answer (score 1):

In `MySQL`:

```
SELECT  CAST(datetime_field AS DATE) AS date_field, SUM(value)
FROM    mytable
GROUP BY
        date_field
```